# Need help starting with Amazon EC2 for a Java project

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

I have been googling all day for a good tutorial to help me start with a basic setup for a Java based web application on Amazon Web Services. The popular ones are outdated and the new ones are unclear. Here are a few doubts I have. Primarily I'm looking for a good "Getting started" tutorial.

- What to choose to create my custom AMI and what is the best way to build it?
- How to configure an EBS volume to store MySQL data and web application project files and how to deploy them from eclipse?
- Is there any best practice for setting up an instance for persistence? Specifically, should I use an EBS-backed AMI or use an instance-store AMI and attach an EBS volume to store persistent data?

Please note that I'm looking for the most basic setup as I'm still in development stage but I should be able to scale the system without much trouble.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom AMI or configure an EBS *through Java*?  Or you just need assistance doing that in general?

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest to try out grails, it is java (groovy) based, open source, and there are some tools to push your app to the cloud backed by amazon (check out http://www.cloudfoundry.com/ from spring) our to appengine.
http://grails.org